# Regular Expressions and multiple strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that matches EXACTLY the following set of strings, I'm super new to RegExp and don't know how to register line breaks:

```
fun  
ab  
acb         
accb  
acccb  
accccb  
....
```

Comment: [`^ac*b$`](https://www.regex101.com/r/KFkkaN/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to include `fun` as one of the options:

```js
function check(string) {
  return /^(?:fun|ac*b)$/.test(string)
}

console.log([
  'fun',      //=> true
  'ab',       //=> true
  'acb',      //=> true
  'accb',     //=> true
  'acccb',    //=> true
  'accccb',   //=> true
  'abc',      //=> false
  'ccccb',    //=> false
  'acccb '    //=> false (note the extra space)
].map(check))
```